# Capybara doesn't wait to complete the submit action on click_button "Save"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I have the following rspec fragment:

```
   describe "Save should create a ClassificationScheme" do
      subject { lambda { click_button "Save"; sleep 1 } }
      it { should change(ClassificationScheme, :count).by(1) 
   end
```

Without the "sleep 1" capybara doesn't wait for the action fired by the save button and the spec fails. With the sleep 1 is OK, but is there any better solution?

Note, that this test is running in Firefox using selenium webdriver.

My versions:

- rails 4.1.12
- rspec 2.99.0
- capybara 2.4.4
- selenium-webdriver 3.2.1
- firefox 51.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include code for your submit action, but if there's anything asynchronous going on, like an Ajax request, the submit action itself will finish quickly, while the async task is still processing the request. If that's the case, you can use a helper like this:

```
# spec/support/wait_for_ajax.rb
module WaitForAjax
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include WaitForAjax, type: :feature
end
```

Code courtesy [Thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara).

**Note** that this only includes the helper in feature specs; so either tag your specs with `type: :feature`, or change the `config.include` line above to include it in whatever spec type you're using.

To use it:

```
describe "Save should create a ClassificationScheme" do
    subject { lambda { click_button "Save"; wait_for_ajax } }
    it { should change(ClassificationScheme, :count).by(1) 
end
```

Comment: wait_for_ajax is a crutch that should be used very rarely, especially as more and more libraries/frameworks move to plain JS rather than utilizing JQuery.   The correct solution is to set an expectation for a visual change on the page.

Comment: I agree, but the question only included a test for a server-side change. Ideally there would be a visual indicator, and that's what the feature spec should look for. Tests for server-side changes like record updates belong in a request spec.

Answer (score 2):

When you click something using Capybara there is no guarantee any actions triggered by that click have completed when the method returns. This is because Capybara knows nothing about what the browser is doing other than that it clicked an element on the screen. Instead of sleeping you need to check for something that visually changes on the page to indicate the action triggered by clicking the button has completed.  That may be a message stating the save happened successfully or an element disappearing, etc.  Something along the lines of

```
describe "Save should create a ClassificationScheme" do
  subject { lambda { click_button "Save"; page.should have_text('Classification Saved' } }
  it { should change(ClassificationScheme, :count).by(1) 
end
```

Note: you should also update Capybara - 2.4.4 was released in October of 2014, there have been a lot of improvements since then.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, what seems to be ok, bit it is not reliable. Sometimes the test fails with the error: `Failure/Error: page.should have_text(I18n.t(:identification) + ':'),   expected to find text "Identification:" in ""`.  The `in ""` is quite suspicious, somehow an intermediate state was cathced by capybara, an empty page.

Comment: @TiborNagy it should like you have `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` set too short for the hardware you're running on. Increase it or pass a `:wait` option to have_text

Comment: I thought it also, but  `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` is already 10.

Comment: @TiborNagy Then you need to check your test log and see what your app is actually doing.  If default_max_wait_time is set to 10 then Capybara will retry for up to 10 seconds for that text to appear which would imply your app isn't returning anything, or there is some weird test interaction.  Another thing to try would be getting rid of the subject and lambda and change matcher and just write out the full test - get the count, click the button, have_text, get count again and compare - to make sure RSpec isn't having a weird interaction with the subject, lambda, and change matcher.